# jQuery unbind not working for me

Tags: jquery

Unbind isn't working for me. Which is weird because it's working in other sections, just not here. Any tips or advice on why it might not be working?

html

```
<ul>
 <li class="articlelibleft_li" onclick="foo()">foo</li>
 <li class="articlelibleft_li_active">foo</li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$('.articlelibleft_li').unbind("click");
```

Comment: What version of jQuery? Try `$('.articlelibleft_li').off('click')`

Comment: Instead of `bind` and `unbind`, use `on` and `off`

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle.net example? And doesn't unbind() only remove handlers bound with bind, not inline?

Comment: `.unbind()` only works with events attached with `.bind()`, not with `onclick=""` -- use `.removeAttr('onclick')` instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for the tip, I did not know that. I tried removeAttr as well but no luck.